Check for library existence in Makefile
Is there a way to check in Makefile whether library (here: librt) is available in a system?
For older systems with librt being in library, not in glibc, I want to test whether it is in a system, if so then link it, if not, then not (as it's not needed).
In other words, in bash it would be something along those lines:
if [ -f /usr/lib/librt.so ] || [ -f /usr/lib/librt.a ]; then
    LIBS=${LIBS} -lrt
fi

But how to do it in Makefile?

make is not intended to be a configuration tool.  That's why things like autoconf exist.  The test you provide above is nowhere near comprehensive; it may work on your personal system but this library could exist in all sorts of other directories on different systems, such as /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so etc. etc.  The only really "correct" way to do this is to try to link without -lrt then if that fails, try again with -lrt (or I suppose the other way around).  What an autoconf configure script would do is try to compile and link a sample program to check this.

I have to say you're right.   I will still accept 'Makefile way' to do the above, how incomprehensive, test. In the last resort in bash way.

Although IMO it's not very useful, you could use this to get what you asked for:
RTLIB_PATHS = /usr/lib/librt.so /usr/lib/librt.a
RTLIB := $(if $(wildcard $(RTLIB_PATHS)),-lrt)

LIBS += $(RTLIB)


It works. I understand limitations but it's good enough for me. I may improve it in a future but it's ok for now.
